# textView goes partially invisible when text is very large android

Tags: android, xml, textview

My question is better understood by the photo I am posting below. The textview is going partially invisible when the text is large. 
[image]

here is the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/txt_date"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:paddingStart="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt_message"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble_send" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_prof"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the adapter

```
if(data.isSend){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_text_send, null);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_message)).setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_message)).setText(data.messageText);
    }else{
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_text_recv, null);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_message)).setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_message)).setText(data.messageText);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why it is happening? I cant figure out, I have similar xml for the other "left" textView, and it is behaving normal.

Comment: I just posted the xml as well as the java code in the adapter

Comment: You can use "show layout bounds" option from the developer option in settings menu to see who is overlapping the textview when there is large text

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your TextView, txt_message

> android:paddingLeft="20dp"

and LinearLayout padding

> android:paddingStart="50dp android:paddingLeft="50dp"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/txt_date"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:paddingStart="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt_message"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble_send"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_prof"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @KasiratKasfi you are welcome! hope it was helpfull.